# how to add mongodb.so extension for mamp pro?

Tags: php, mongodb, mamp-pro

I follow the following steps:

1. install mamp pro from [MAMP Website](https://www.mamp.info)
2. git clone mongodb driver from github

   git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver.git
   cd mongo-php-driver
   git submodule update --init
   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/phpize
   ./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php-config
   make all
   sudo make install
3. open mamp pro -> file -> Edit Template -> php, add
   `extension=mongodb.so`.
4. restart mamp pro.  click web start, click phpinfo, search `mongo`. 
   none!!

can somebody help me figure out why mongodb.so not working?

Answer (score 3):

try this, it's working

```
1, goto [php official site][1] download php.5.6.x
2，unpack the file, paste it to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.x/inclue/, you need mkdir and remaned to dirname php
3, drag ../include/php folder to terminal screen, and run:   ./configure
4, run:  sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.x/bin/pecl install mongo  or mongodb
5, go to mamp pro->file->php template->php5.6.x.ini, paste ,just like 

extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.22/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mongo.so

extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.22/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mongodb.so

6, restart mamp pro -> webstart page-> phpinfo -> search mongo yeah, have them, enjoy it.
```

Comment: missing link to the official site